# Kaspersky Antivirus exclusion definition for files within composite files/archives

Tags: anti-virus, kaspersky

We regularly get virus notifications for a legitimate component within our develop/test chain, for which I have attempted to define an exclusion.  However, I can't seem to get this exclusion to be honoured.

The 'virus' is reported as `not-a-virus:NetTool.Win32.ProxySwitcher.d` in `X:\pathto\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar//hudsuckr/hudsuckr.exe`, which appears to be an attempt by the tool maker to package one app within another.  There are different paths and versions of Selenium in use (selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar also occurs frequently).

I am trying to apply as narrow an exception as possible, while still being reasonable with respect to the various versions in play.  The exception I have defined (which does not work) is:

- Object to scan:   `selenium-server-standalone-*.jar\hudsuckr\hudsuckr.exe`
- Objects to check: `not-a-virus:NetTool.Win32.ProxySwitcher.*`

The documentation suggests I should be able to use `*` as a wildcard for both object names and virus names.  The GUI will not let me distinguish between `//`, `/` and `\` and silently converts all to `\`.

The AV setup is a mix of *Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10 Maintenance Release 1 for Windows* and *Kaspersky Anti-Virus 8.0 for Windows Servers Enterprise Edition* (depending on target system).  The exception is defined in centralised policies, which apply to both versions.

What is the correct way to apply the exception, in this instance?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Kaspersky? I have always found them helpful when I have raised a support request.

Comment: @AFH - your experience with vendor support is far different from mine...

Comment: OK. It's a couple of years since my last problem. I still find them the best package: low impact and very configurable (though I have not needed to implement your exception). Maybe you should try excluding `NetTool.Win32.ProxySwitcher.d` as a general virus exception without trying to specify its location. Nearly all the first page searches for this virus string refer to your problem.